# Having clause skips even values of computed field

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Scenario: A queue of items to process only 100 items per user per day.

Explanation: Here is self join of past 24 hours' processed record with unprocessed items with remaining per day quota.

```
SELECT 
    q.*, 
    case when delivery.processed is null then 0 else delivery.processed end as processed, 
    @subcounter := IF(@context = q.user_id, @subcounter+1, 1) as counter,
    @context := q.user_id as uid 
from queue q

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `user_id`, count(*) as `processed` FROM `queue` 
    where `status` = 'processed' and `updated_at` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
    GROUP BY `user_id`) as `delivery`
    ON `delivery`.`user_id` = `q`.`user_id`

WHERE 
    `q`.`status` = 'queued' and 
    (`delivery`.`processed` is null or `delivery`.`processed` < 100)
HAVING
    `counter` <= (100 - `delivery`.`processed`)
```

The final condition `counter <= (100 - delivery.processed)` is erroneous to skip every alternate row where counter is even.

Without this final condition I cannot skip records those are going to exceed the daily quota limit of 100.

```
Table: queue
Columns:
id  bigint(20) UN AI PK
created_at  timestamp
updated_at  timestamp
job_id  bigint(20)
user_id bigint(20)
status  varchar(64)
```

Here is the query result: (2nd last column missing sequence, skipping all evens numbers due to having clause condition)

```
'224244', '2016-03-24 22:44:32', '2016-03-24 22:44:32', '23942', '3', 'queued', '0', '1', '3'
'224995', '2016-03-24 22:45:25', '2016-03-24 22:45:25', '23963', '3', 'queued', '0', '3', '3'
'225208', '2016-03-24 22:45:40', '2016-03-24 22:45:40', '23970', '3', 'queued', '0', '5', '3'
'225316', '2016-03-24 22:45:47', '2016-03-24 22:45:47', '23972', '3', 'queued', '0', '7', '3'
'227247', '2016-03-27 15:17:00', '2016-03-27 15:17:00', '22741', '3', 'queued', '0', '9', '3'
'227258', '2016-03-27 15:17:00', '2016-03-27 15:17:00', '22747', '3', 'queued', '0', '11', '3'
'228291', '2016-03-27 15:18:22', '2016-03-27 15:18:22', '24537', '3', 'queued', '0', '13', '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an extra layer -- and extra `SELECT` around what you have.  Except, move the `HAVING` in the outermost, at which point you can change it to `WHERE`.